# Is it a good practice to have a hash table with so many keys in Redis?

Tags: redis

I'm making a reverse search type of function for a project, and the way I was planning for it to work is by having the problem already solved from the start, and for that I was planning to use a table that saves every element as a key, and its containers as an array, kind of like this:

```
REVERSE
|- "Element_1_id": '["container_1_id", "container_2_id"]'
|- "Element_2_id": '["contianer_1_id", "container_3_id"]'
...
```

And this way, When I want to search for "where is Element 1 contained?", I can know immediatly the containers ID by getting the hash for the element id, and I'll only need to manage things when adding or removing from a container. But this made me think: It is a good idea to do this, or if could this be a bad practice? I don't have a lot of experience with Redis, so I'm not sure if having a Hash with so many keys could break something.

Need to mention that for this case, Elements is an N number that can go to infinite(Although it doesn't grow so fast). Based on a quick search, it seems like the only 2 limitations are: A Hash has a limit of 2³² keys(Which I'm not sure how much of a limit could be considered, because even if the number of elements can grow that big, maybe will not get to that in this life), and memory of the platform, which might be a very big issue(Since the platform could be as simple as an RPi), but I'm not sure if Redis has some kind of memory optimization process for tables this big. What do you think? Is this a viable solution, or should I discard this option for bad practice, and try an standard search algorithm?

Answer (score 0):

As you point out there's a limitation on how many fields can live in a single hash, plus the overall limit of how much memory you have on a single Redis instance.  If you want to scale this to a Redis cluster you'd want to use different keys for each name/value pair that you currently have in the hash.  These could then be scaled across multiple Redis server instances operating as a cluster as needed.

If you are able to use Redis Stack, you might want to look at the search capability there.  This would allow you to store your data as hashes or JSON documents in Redis then search them efficiently and at scale.  For your data, I'd suggest small JSON documents to replace each hash name/value pair.